# Mantener el textbox del designer como public static, pero cambia solo. C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, object, ado.net

estoy trabajando con ADO.NET, he logrado hacer una conexion y insertar datos pero quisiera saber si hay una forma de dejar definitivamente el textbox como public static para poder acceder; cada vez que cambio el forms con designer vuelve a estar como antes y debo de volver a dejar el codigo del designer.cs como antes quitandome tiempo, no habra una forma en propiedades del visual studio que pueda hacer eso???, si no la hay entonces como puedo pasar datos de un textbox a una variable en otra clase diferente?

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label_nombre;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label_matricula;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label_carrera;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label_cuatrimestre;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button guardar;
    private FormularioDataSet formularioDataSet;
    private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource estudianteBindingSource;
    private FormularioDataSetTableAdapters.EstudianteTableAdapter estudianteTableAdapter;
    public DataGridViewTextBoxColumn idEstudianteDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    public DataGridViewTextBoxColumn matriculaDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    public DataGridViewTextBoxColumn nombreDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    public DataGridViewTextBoxColumn carreraDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    public DataGridViewTextBoxColumn cuatrimestreDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    public static TextBox txt_matricula; //ha
    public static TextBox txt_nombre;      // estos de
    public static TextBox txt_carrera;        // aca me 
    public static TextBox txt_cuatrimestre;      // refiero
    public static DataGridView dataGridView1;
```

Comment: pero no deberias tocar el codigo del designer, eso es codigo que el Visual Studio regenera constantemente en base al diseño visual que se realice, no debes poner codigo alli, si lo haces es incorrecto

Comment: No estoy añadiendo código ahí, lo único que hice fue cambiar los textbox de privados a public static para poder acceder directamente desde otra clase :/

Comment: Saludos Allyson, bienvenido a SOes, sólo por curiosidad, ¿cómo estás aprendiendo a programar?

Comment: Es que cambiar de private a public es lo mismo, porque el codigo en el designe se regenera,no tienes control en ese codigo. Ademas tienes la propiedad Modifiers para definir si es public

Comment: solo estaba haciendo pruebas con el designer de visual studio, ya que es mi primera vez que lo utilizo, (uso netbeans para java), y habitualmente si necesito cambiar el tipo de acceso, el netbeans me da la posibilidad, pero solo estaba probandolo, se que lo que estaba haciendo era una mala practica, nota: estudio la carrera de software desde hace un año y medio ;)

Answer (score 0):

Partamos de la base que a una clase no se e pasa ningun textbox ni tampoco deberia acceder a este. Se supone que debes pasar datos simple por parametro

Si defines la clase

```
public class ClassEjemplo{

   public void Metodo1(string nombre){
      //aqui codigo
   } 
}
```

Entonce desde el form usarias esa funcionalidad

```
public class Form1{

    public void button1_click(...)
    {
        ClassEjemplo obj = new ClassEjemplo();
        obj.Metodo1(txt_nombre.Text);
    }
}
```

instancias la clase y le pasas el `string` por parametro que sera el contenido del textbox, peor no pasas nunca el textbox como objeto

Comment: Muchas gracias por aclararme en ese aspecto, ahora veo que lo que estaba haciendo era una mala práctica :)

Comment: http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2010/05/login-usando-password-con-hash.html leandro, usted hizo este tutorial, alguna forma de descargar el codigo fuente, he tratado de hacerlo y no me funciona, aparte no me deja descargar los archivos